# Avoid browser cache from JS GET request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have service which adds Cache header to response to cache content by browser. In some JS requests i need to force reload this data avoiding browser cache.
Is it possible?

```
- ASP MVC (i;m adding CacheControlHeaderValue with expiration date)
- Angular js ($resource call)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea about ASP.NET

However, I assume you want to fetch the fresh response each time you make a request and not get the cached data.

The concept is popular as a "Cache Slayer". Please refer this [gist](https://gist.github.com/twilson63/8578778) which contains the entire code.

The idea is to add a query parameter each time a request is carried out. The query parameter will contain the current time and thus the request is unique and forces the browser to get the latest response and not the cached one - a technique used frequently with Internet Explorer.